# TypeError: undefined is not a function even though i created this function

Tags: javascript, typeerror

There is a fair amount to this project, but I am new to javascript and am getting "TypeError: undefined is not a function" even though I have created the function with the correct name (in a different javascript file).

Error message;

```
C:\Users\Matt\Documents\GitHub\SnailsBattleground>node app.js
Server listening to port 9001
Attempt to load C:\Users\Matt\Documents\GitHub\SnailsBattleground/index.html
express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead app.js:24:6
express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead app.js:33:6
C:\Users\Matt\Documents\GitHub\SnailsBattleground\app.js:58
    gameServer.findGame(client);
               ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Namespace.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Matt\Documents\GitHub\SnailsBattleground\
app.js:58:13)
at Namespace.emit (events.js:107:17)
at Namespace.emit (C:\Users\Matt\Documents\GitHub\SnailsBattleground\node_mo
dules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:205:10)
at C:\Users\Matt\Documents\GitHub\SnailsBattleground\node_modules\socket.io\
lib\namespace.js:172:14
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Here is where it is called;

```
socket.sockets.on("connection", function(client) {
    client.userid = UUID();

    client.emit("onconnected", {
        id: client.userid
    });

    gameServer.findGame(client);

    console.log("New player " + client.userid + "has joined.");

    client.on("message", function(m) {
        gameServer.delayMessage(client, m);
    });

    client.on("disconnect", function() {
        console.log("Player " + client.userid + "has disconnected.");

        //end the game if the client is disconnected 
        if (client.game && client.game.id) {
            gameServer.endGame(client.game.id, client.userid);
        }
    });
});
```

And here it is in gameServer.js;

```
gameServer.findGame = function(player){
    this.log('looking for a game. We have : ' + this.gameCount);
    if(this.gameCount){
        var joinGame = false;

            for(var gameId in this.games) {
            if(!this.games.hasOwnProperty(gameId)) continue;

            var gameInst = this.games[gameId];

            if(gameInst.playerCount < 2) {
                joinGame = true;

                gameInst.playerClient = player;
                gameInst.gameMg.players.other.instance = player;
                gameInst.playerCount++;

                this.startGame(gameInst);
            }
        }
        if(!joinGame){
            this.createGame(player);
        }
    }
    else {
        this.createGame(player);
    }
};
```

It is likely some silly can't see though. Thanks for any help

Comment: do you require the gameServer file and export the findGame function from it?
https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: Also, did you create an object `gameserver` before attaching a function to its property `findGame`?

Comment: @puelo the gameServer.findGame function is within the gameServer.js file and I call it in app.js, and i have game_server = require('./game.server.js'); before it in the app.js file

Comment: @MatthewWren If you have game_server = require('./game.server.js');, shouldn't the call to findGame be game_server.findGame(client);?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, what you're doing is odd. The simplest answer in node is for you to export whatever code you are using in gameServer.js and then store it in a var inside of your app.

```
//in gameServer.js
exports.findGame = function(){//do Stuff};

//in App.js
var gameServer = require("./pathToFile/gameServer.js");
gameServer.findGame();
```